# Add data to datasource wildfly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm hosting a Java web application using WildFly, I configured the datasource and launched the application. The application contains a login screen at first (which gets the username and password from the database) initially the database is empty, and I don't know how to add any records in it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple straightforward ways of achieving this:

1. For Hibernate, use the *import.sql* functionality built into Hibernate (I'm assuming Hibernate since the question is tagged as such) [Here's a link to a Wildfly quickstart that uses this file](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/hibernate/src/main/resources/import.sql)
2. For JPA, look into the *javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source* persistence unit property. [Link to page about schema creation, but mentions this property and example setting](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm)

**Side Note:** If you're using EJB in your project, and need to handle this data creation in Java, take a look at the *@Startup* annotation, that can be used to run code when your application first deploys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured out that to use import.sql you must make the hbm2ddl to create, won't work with update